# Set axis in ggplot2 like in plot

Tags: r

is there a way to set axis in ggplot2 in this way (made with plot())?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What aspects of these axes are you trying to copy - the appearance, the formatting, the exact ticks and number positions?  What is the data you are using?

Comment: Perhaps using [theme_tufte()](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggthemes/man/theme_tufte.html) and [geom_rangeframe()](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggthemes/man/geom_rangeframe.html) from the ggthemes package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what aspect you are looking for, so here's a recreation of every aspect:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) x, color = NA, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-450, -300, -20, 0, 300, 450), 
                     limits = c(-500, 500), name = NULL, expand = c(0, 0),
                     labels = c(-450, -300, -20, "", 300, 450)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2014.5, 2019.5),  expand = c(0, 0),
                     breaks = 2015:2019, name = NULL) +
  annotate('segment', x = 2014.5, y = -450, xend = 2014.5, yend = 450, size = 1) +
  annotate('segment', x = 2015, y = -500, xend = 2019, yend = -500, size = 1) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(3, 'mm'))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I just need to split x-y axes no matter the values they have